# Bookmark all tabs in Chrome on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, tabs, bookmarks

Is there is a way to bookmark all of my tabs at once without having to go one by one while in Chrome for iOS?

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to do this in Google Chrome for iOS.

However there is a work around:

It requires you to have sync enabled on both your iOS device and a Mac or PC running the desktop Google Chrome OS.

1. On the desktop computre launch Chrome, then go to the menu bar, and select `History > Show Full History` or press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.
2. On the left side select "Tabs from other devices".
3. Find your device in the list and in the right corner press the three dots icon.
4. Now choose "Open all".
5. This will open every tab from your iPhone in a new window.
6. Now click "Bookmarks" from the menu bar and select "Bookmark All Tabs..." or press <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

You will now be able to save all these tabs as bookmarks and that group will sync back to your phone due to the sync feature you already enabled.

***Based on a tip from***: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/1fqaxc/how_to_bookmark_all_tabs_in_chrome/)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. I can see my desktop from my iOS device, but not vice versa. I can also see one computer from another, but not the iOS devices. Thanks though.

Comment: You may need to check your sync settings @ngundling but it should work if you followed the steps, I verified this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there wasn’t a way when this question was originally asked, or maybe how to accomplish this in a straightforward manner just wasn’t - as it has remained until now - well known or intuitive. As you may surmise, the question has come to mind more than once over the years and recently, I decided to figure it out, and I share the results here for anyone else that may find themselves asking and searching the Internet for a straightforward and sensible answer.

Here it is: [How to bookmark all tabs in Chrome for iOS](https://www.killsignal.net/mobile_chrome_bookmarks/)

From the linked page:

> With Chrome loaded and in the foreground, press the square at the bottom of the screen that is either displaying a two-digit integer, or shows a sideways ASCII smiley face emoticon.
> Tap "Edit" at the bottom left of the Chrome screen. The "Select Tabs" and "Close All Tabs" menu will appear just above where you tapped.
> Tapping on "Select Tabs" will display the "Select All", "Select Tabs", and "Done" options at the top of the screen, and little hollow blue circles will appear on the tab thumbnails, allowing them to be toggled as selected or not.
> Tap "Select All" in the top left.
> all of the hollow circles in the top right of every tab thumbnail have become solid blue circles with white check marks on them.
> At the top of the screen, flanked on either side by "Deselect All"" and "Done", you will see a number. This number is the total number of open tabs in Chrome on your iOS device which you are about to bookmark.
> select "Add to Bookmarks".

Some may find the link easier to follow than the quoted text above, since it includes screenshots from my iPhone while walking through it.